# New Android SDK Tools causing havok

Tags: android

I've just updated to the new sdk platform version 11 and tools version 10 and they now generate invalid .apk files. Eclipse doesn't complain until I try and install it, then says

> Android Launch!
>
> adb is running normally.
>
> Could not find someapp.apk!

This is because the apk is messed up. Using `adb install someapp.apk` we see

> EOCD not found, not Zip

Note, I'm building against 2 referenced libraries.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent the day looking for an answer, and much to my chagrin was unable to find answer. I did narrow the culprit down to either Eclipse 3.4 or Ant though.
My reasoning: Ant 1.8 is needed to use the command line tools, I updated and could build via command line. Eclipse has plugins for 1.7 though, so builds still failed.

To solve this, I updated to Eclipse 3.6 and everything works now. Hopefully this helps someones else.